# Сортировка с помощью reverse и проверки

Tags: сортировка

Есть последовательность, её нужно отсортировать с помощью двух операций: reverse(l,r) - перевернуть подпоследовательность
IsSort(l,r) - проверить подпоследовательность на отсортированность
Прямое обращение, сравнение, копирование - нельзя.
Всего должно быть O(logn) вызовов этих операций

Я ничего лучше, чем пузырёк, не придумал..

Answer (score 1):

> Всего должно быть O(logn) вызовов этих операций

Хрень. Наилучшая сложность для алгоритма сортировки - O(n). Ещё лучше просто не бывает. Может, O(n*logn)?

============

Пусть у нас есть некоторая подпоследовательность, которая уже отсортирована. Берём примыкающий к ней "новый" элемент. Реверсим его вместе с половиной сортированной подпоследовательности, после чего реверсим только сортированный кусок. Проверяем этот кусок на сортированность. Если да - то по тому же алгоритму обрабатываем новый плюс вторую сортированную половинку (деление пополам и проверка), если нет - то вторую четвертинку первой половинки. Так половинным делением "встраиваем" этот новый элемент на своё место получая новую сортированную последовательность, на 1 элемент длиннее. Это первый суб-алгоритм, псевдо-реализация пузырька, используется для коротких, не более 4 элементов, блоков.

Второй суб-алгоритм. Имеются две отсортированные подпоследовательности непосредственно друг за другом длины M и N. Обрабатываем по первому алгоритму первую подпоследовательность плюс первый элемент второй. На выходе - две отсортированные подпоследовательности непосредственно друг за другом длины M+1 и N-1, но, кроме того, известна та часть сортированной первой подпоследовательности, в которую следует вставлять следующий элемент второй подпоследовательности. Почти эмуляция слияния.

Итоговую сложность оценить не берусь. не профи, но получится точно не хуже  O(n*n). А скорее всего лучше.